# The init.rc file regenerated on restart

Tags: android, shell

I have added some script to start my application in `init.rc` file. But when I restart the emulator the file gets changed to its original file. I want that the changes made by me should not be removed on start-up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The init.rc file is part of the ramdisk.img you will need to unpack the ramdisk.img file in the avd make any modifications are repack it.

On linux it can be unpacked with the following commands

```
mkdir ramdisk && cd ramdisk
gunzip -c ../ramdisk.img | cpio -i
```

modify the init.rc as you please and then repack it with

```
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../new_ramdisk.img
```