# How to create a directory in /data folder in android

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to create a directory in /data folder in a Rooted android device using application. I am trying two ways, first by using mkdirs() method, and other by executing the Runtime.exec(). Following is the code :

```
String path = "/data/abc";
File abc = new File(path);
Process proc = runtime.exec("chmod 777 /data");
proc.waitFor();
proc = runtime.exec("mkdir " + path);
```

Of course, if I go to 'adb shell' and simply run the command

```
#mkdir /data/abc
```

It works. But How do I do it via application. Following is the other way -

```
String path = "/data/abc";
File abc = new File(path);
boolean isDirCreated = abc.mkdirs();
```

I am not getting the required folder created in /data folder.
I already have the permission in Manifest file of writing external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Kindly suggest any way to do so.

Comment: Does mkdirs() throw any exception?

Comment: Did you give root permissions to your app?

Comment: @WojciechKo No, mkdirs() doesn't throw anything, it just returns false. Well the javadoc of mkdirs() also doesn't throw anything, it returns 'boolean'.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card

Comment: @m0skit0 How do I give root permission to an android app?

Comment: @codeMan As per the reference, I am getting an issue while running 'wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();' It is returning false.

Comment: @  darthvading
 

File.mkdirs() will only return true once: when the directories actually had to be created. From the documentation:

    returns true if the necessary directories have been created, false if the target directory already exists or one of the directories can not be created.

Comment: @darthvading Aslo.. is there any specific reason for not using the /sdcard for creating the folder?

Comment: @codeMan  Well I have already been through the documentation of mkdirs(), it returns true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise.

Comment: @darthvading are your sure the directory already does not exists?

Comment: @codeMan  I am specifically interested in /data folder, coz currently I am playing with some Android OS features. But this issue(seemed so minor in the beginning) is becoming quite a headache.

Comment: @codeMan yes, that directory is definitely not existing already, that was the most obvious thing I was expecting to happen. Anyway, if it were existing, my code would have been working smoothly, as I was not monitoring the 'false' earlier.

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not needed as /data is clearly internal memory. And if your app does not request root permissions first then it will never work.

Comment: @greenapps  How does an app request root permissions? I already tried executing the 'proc = runtime.exec("su mkdir " + path);' command. It too didn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Just search/google for "requesting root access in your app". It is not trivial though.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [How to create directory automatically on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card)

Maybe you need to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

#### Update:

From this question: [Create a folder and write into it in the root of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587458/create-a-folder-and-write-into-it-in-the-root-of-android)
Not sure if it's 100% correct but should work:

```
String path = "/data/abc";
String cmd = "mkdir " + path;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
os.write(cmd.getBytes());
os.flush();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: @WojciechKo Does the phone have to be rooted to execute the above code?

Comment: @codeMan I guess so. Without root, `su` authentication should fail.

Comment: @WojciechKo I tried the "su" version too now, not helpful.

Comment: @darthvading As WojciechKo  has mentioned, You need root permissions to create a folder in the /data/ directory, which you might not have, instead, if useful, you can create the directory in /sdcard.

Comment: @codeMan  I tried already using 'Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");' It didn't work. I have to create directory in '/data/' not in '/sdcard/'